# Form validation in JSP using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      *{
             font-family: cursive;
       }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validate()
            {
                var a = document.getElementById("a");
                var b = document.getElementById("b");
                var valid = true;
                if(a.value.length<=0 || b.value.length<=0)
                    {
                        alert("Don't leave the field empty!");
                        valid = false;
                    }
                    else{
                        if(!IsNumeric(a.value) || !IsNumeric(b.value))
                            alert("Enter a number");
                    valid = false;
                }
                return valid;
            };

        </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#CDCDCC" font-family="cursive" font-size="20px;" font-weight="bold">



    <h2>Welcome <%=request.getParameter("uname")%>! Enter the numbers and the operation that you want to perform: </h2>
    <form font-size="75px;" action ="serv" method="get" onsubmit="return validate();" >
        <hr/>
        Enter the 1st number: <input type="text" name="a" /><br/>

        Enter the 2st number: <input type="text" name="b" /><br/><br/>

       <label>Add</label><input type="radio" name="option" value="Add" /><br/>

       <label>Subtract</label><input type="radio" name="option" value="Subtract"/><br/>

       <label>Multiply</label><input type="radio" name="option" value="Multiply"/><br/>

       <label>Divide</label><input type="radio" name="option" value="Divide" /><br/>

       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />


   </form>


</body>
```

This is my JSP and I've written a JavaScript function `validate()` that validates the user input against blank space and String. 
My problem is that when i click on the submit button, for correct integer input, it is working. If an invalid input is given, i get a blank page. Can someone help me out with what the problem is and what is that i should modify? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In you javascript you are checking via ID but there is no ID for input fields.

```
<input type="text" name="a" id ="a"/>
<input type="text" name="b" id="b" />
```

to check if a input is string or not use `isNAN()` like the following way

```
if(isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)){
alert("enter a number");}
```

Following is the complete working example

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      *{
             font-family: cursive;
       }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validate()
            {
                var a = document.getElementById("a");
                var b = document.getElementById("b");
                var c = document.getElementById("a").value;
                var d = document.getElementById("b").value;
                var valid = true;
                if(a.value.length<=0 || b.value.length<=0)
                    {
                        alert("Don't leave the field empty!");
                        valid = false;
                    }
                    else{
                        if(isNaN(c) || isNaN(d)){
                            alert("Enter a number");
                    valid = false;}
                }
                return valid;
            };
        </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#CDCDCC" font-family="cursive" font-size="20px;" font-weight="bold">

    <h2>Welcome <%=request.getParameter("uname")%>! Enter the numbers and the operation that you want to perform: </h2>
    <form font-size="75px;" action ="serv" method="get" onsubmit="return validate();" >
        <hr/>
        Enter the 1st number: <input type="text" name="a" id="a" /><br/>

        Enter the 2st number: <input type="text" name="b" id="b" /><br/><br/>

       <label>Add</label><input type="radio" name="option" value="Add" /><br/>

       <label>Subtract</label><input type="radio" name="option" value="Subtract"/><br/>

       <label>Multiply</label><input type="radio" name="option" value="Multiply"/><br/>

       <label>Divide</label><input type="radio" name="option" value="Divide" /><br/>

       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong but your javascript function is looking for 'a' and 'b' **IDs** 
And you don't have such... your input elements got names. add ids attributes...

Comment: My bad. I've added the ID's now. But still, when i submit all i get is a blank page!